Как обрезать лишние байты после расшифровки DES?
Был зашифрован файл на языке java. Я же пытаюсь его расшифровать на языке D.
Надо расшифровать файл. С самой дешифрацией проблем не возникло. Нашел алгоритм на просторах гитхаба. Получаю исходную строку. В этом проблем нет.
Но... Дело в том, что строки у DES кратны 8-ми. И если не хватает длинны, то в конец пишутся случайные байты.
И у меня встала проблема. Я получаю строку, у которой на конце мусорные байты.
Как мне их отследить, чтобы обрезать и получить строку без мусора?
Вот сам код расшифровки (если надо могу еще скинуть код, который я портировал по ссылке ниже)
// Читаем файл
ubyte[] bytes = file.rawRead(new ubyte[needed]);

// Исходная строка
ubyte[] o;

// Дешифруем
ubyte[8] PT;
ubyte[8] CT;
for (size_t readed = 0; readed < needed; readed += 8) {
    CT = bytes[readed..readed+8];
    decrypt_block( &PT[0], &CT[0], &myskey[0] );

    o ~= PT;
}

return to!string(cast(char[])o);

Код подсмотрел от сюда: https://github.com/delhatch/DES_decrypt/blob/master/des_decrypt.cpp

Выяснить какой алгоритм паддинга использовался и отрезать лишние байты. https://asecuritysite.com/symmetric/padding_des

Спасибо. Прочитал по ссылке и оказалось, что у меня в конце мусор указывает на число сколько байт мусора в блоке. Написал небольшой код, который смотрит последний байт.
И если последний байт меньше или равно 8 пробегается в обратном порядке по массиву и ищет такойже байт подряд.
И действительно сработало. Теперь все дешифруется без мусора!
